# How to add a new "From" email address in civi mailing - cannot find function following the update

Tags: civimail

I used to be able to add new "from" email addresses for civi mailing, but I cannot find the location anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE. I don't think it has moved. It is under Administer >> CiviMail >> From Email Addresses.